# Docker-compose up giving Resource ID ERROR

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

getting below error while running docker-compose up .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/garvit/.local/bin/docker-compose", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/garvit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
  File "/home/garvit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 203, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/home/garvit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/metrics/decorator.py", line 18, in wrapper
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/garvit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1186, in up
    to_attach = up(False)
  File "/home/garvit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1166, in up
    return self.project.up(
  File "/home/garvit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/project.py", line 664, in up
    svc.ensure_image_exists(do_build=do_build, silent=silent, cli=cli)
  File "/home/garvit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 352, in ensure_image_exists
    self.image()
  File "/home/garvit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 378, in image
    return self.client.inspect_image(self.image_name)
  File "/home/garvit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py",
```

line 16, in wrapped

```
    raise errors.NullResource(
docker.errors.NullResource: Resource ID was not provided
```

Below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
#  broker:
#    container_name: broker
#    env_file:
#      - .env
#    networks:
#      - broker
#    image: "docker.io/bitnami/rabbitmq:latest"
#    environment:
#      - RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=${BROKER_PASSWORD}
#      - RABBITMQ_USERNAME=${PROD}
#    ports:
#      - "4369:4369"
#      - "5672:5672"
#      - "25672:25672"
#      - "15672:15672"
#    volumes:
#      - "pdf_broker_data:/bitnami"

  web:
    build: ./src
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env.sample
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

  graphql-engine:
    image: ${HASURA_VERSION}
    ports:
      - "5001:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://${DB_USERNAME}:${DB_PASSWORD}@db:5432/${DB_NAME}
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLED_LOG_TYPES: startup, http-log, webhook-log, websocket-log, query-log
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: ${HASURA_ADMIN_PASS}

#  webserver:
#    build: .
#    # image: mpc-etl:latest
#    restart: always
#    env_file:
#      - pdf/.env
#    depends_on:
#      - db
#    volumes:
#      - ./logs:/srv/logs/
#    ports:
#      - "8080:8080"
#    command: gunicorn --workers=2 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 app:api
#    healthcheck:
#      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://webserver:8080"]
#      interval: 2s
#      timeout: 2s
#      retries: 5
#
#  worker:
#    build: .
#    # image: mpc-etl:latest
#    restart: always
#    env_file:
#      - pdf/.env
#    depends_on:
#      - db
#      - broker
#    volumes:
#      - ./logs:/srv/logs/
#    command: celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=info

#volumes:
#  pdf_broker_data:
#    driver: local

#networks:
#  broker:
#    driver: bridge
```

i have tried deleting the all docker packages and then reinstalling them and also i have tried to rebuild the docker-compose --build .

i want to know how to resolve this error.

Note - this error is coming in inside UBUNTU (WSL).

Comment: show us your docker-compose file.

Comment: i have added it in the question plz have a look at it

Comment: take a look here https://github.com/mattd429/flask-apollo-react-hooks-docker-graphql,just add data base and it should work.

Comment: The environment variable `$HASURA_VERSION` needs to be set either on your host system when you run `docker-compose up` or in a `.env` file; is it set in either of these places?

Comment: yes the $HASURA_VERSION is set inside my .env file {HASURA_VERSION=hasura/graphql-engine:latest}